# What's the most lightweight option to forward mail on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, mail-forwarding, lightweight

I want to setup mail forwarding on my Ubuntu 12.04. It will be only used to forward mail to several existing custom domain Gmail accounts. What is the most lightwieght option to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my preferred method would be to use postfix and configure the aliases in /etc/aliases if there are not many, or they wont change often. If you don't like postfix you can do the same with most popular MTAs. They are all pretty light weight in the grand scheme of things unless you bolt on a heap of anti-spam stuff. If you need more managable aliases, you could do it through mysql also, but that would obviously add overhead.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access to the machine, you can use /etc/aliases. But if you don't have root access, you can forward your own account by editing ~/.forward